Do these count as "third-party content"?
Do either of these count as "third-party content" in the context of the Contents Rights declaration for an app?

Fonts by other authors that I am permitted to use commercially.

A relatively simple third-party script for an online high-score system that I am also allowed to use commercially.


I have listed both in the copyright/credits in my app (a game). Although I say commercially, this app will be free with no in-app purchases.

Can you add a link to the specific document that refers to "third-party content"?

@Barmar It's a question in App Information in App Store Connect (accessible to those subscribed to the Apple Developer Program). Here is the text:
Content Rights
Apps that contain, show, or access third-party content must have all the necessary rights to that content or be otherwise permitted to use it under the laws of each country or region in which they're available.
Does your app contain, show, or access third-party content?
_ Yes, it contains, shows, or accesses third-party content, and I have the necessary rights
_ No, it does not contain, show, or access third-party content

I don't see your comments relating to any of the three "third party" mentions in this https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ - what specific guideline or policy from Apple are you referring to?

Yes this is third-party content. When you answer Yes, a second question will be asked for you to provide details. This is where you explain those two bullet points as you have done in the question here, showing that you have permission.
